# group data which are either 0 or 1

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector `Blinks` whose values are either `0` or `1`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Blinks = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)
)
```

I want to insert a grouping variable for when `Blinks == 1`. I'm using `rleid`for this but the grouping seems to count in the instances where `Blinks == 0`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
  mutate(Blinks_grp = ifelse(Blinks > 0, rleid(Blinks), Blinks))
       Blinks Blinks_grp
    1       0          0
    2       0          0
    3       1          2
    4       1          2
    5       1          2
    6       0          0
    7       0          0
    8       1          4
    9       1          4
    10      1          4
    11      1          4
    12      0          0
    13      0          0
    14      1          6
    15      1          6
```

How can I obtain the **correct result**:

```
    1       0          0
    2       0          0
    3       1          1
    4       1          1
    5       1          1
    6       0          0
    7       0          0
    8       1          2
    9       1          2
    10      1          2
    11      1          2
    12      0          0
    13      0          0
    14      1          3
    15      1          3
```

Comment: If `Blinks` is binary won't `rleid(Blinks)/2` do the trick? [Goes to check...]  Yes, it will.

Comment: @Limey ...however not very general, `rleid(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)) / 2`

Comment: @Henrik.  True.  Wrapping in `ceiling()` takes care of the case when the target value is in the first element of the vector.  So, with `x <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)`, as in your counter example, `ceiling(ifelse(x > 0, rleid(x)/2, x))` gives the desired result succinctly without changing the result for OP's use case.

Comment: Indeed! Or slightly more compact `ceiling(rleid(x) * x / 2)`. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Blinks_grp = with(rle(Blinks), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths)))

   Blinks Blinks_grp
1       0          0
2       0          0
3       1          1
4       1          1
5       1          1
6       0          0
7       0          0
8       1          2
9       1          2
10      1          2
11      1          2
12      0          0
13      0          0
14      1          3
15      1          3
```